# How to dynamically calculate distance between 2 markers in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am still very new to JavaScript and struggling with an assignment using JS Leaflet. I am supposed to map the user as well as a series of features (polygons) on the map, and add popups to the latter. In the popup some info is specified, including the distance from user to the features. 
I am supposed to use module revealing pattern to solve this.

So, I have been able to solve the mapping, but I am not able to calculate the distance between user and features, since user location won't update properly. I have used a global variable which is supposed to be updated inside locate function, but the update doesn't happen as expected for some reason.

It feels like I'm missing something fundamental related to javascript behavior/ revealing module pattern, but I am not sure what it is.
All help appreciated, code below:

```
var mapApp = (function() {
  var foos = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: [
      {
        type: "Feature",
        properties: {
          title: "title",
          description: "desc",
          logo: "img.png",
          distance: 0
        },
        geometry: {
          type: "Polygon",
          coordinates: [
            [
              [13.192812502384186, 55.7029732524422],
              [13.192858099937439, 55.7029732524422],
              [13.192858099937439, 55.70300045726667],
              [13.192812502384186, 55.70300045726667],
              [13.192812502384186, 55.7029732524422]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  var map = L.map("map", {
    center: [55.70293, 13.192945],
    zoom: 18
  });

  var myPosition = L.marker(map._lastCenter);

  function init() {
    L.tileLayer(
      "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}",
      {
        attribution:
          'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 19,
        id: "mapbox.streets"
      }
    ).addTo(map);

    addFeatures();
    locateUser();
  }

  function locateUser() {
    var myPositionIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: "icon.png",
      iconSize: [32, 32]
    });

    map
      .locate({
        setView: false,
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        watch: false,
        maxZoom: 13
      })
      .on("locationfound", function myPositionFound(e) {
        //displaying my location on the map with icon if position found
        // updating global variable myPosition
        myPosition = L.marker(e.latlng, {
          icon: myPositionIcon
        }).addTo(map);
        console.log("User position: ", myPosition.getLatLng()); //my position coordinates are ok in the console, but myPosition doesn't get updated
        calculateDistances(myPosition.getLatLng());
      })
      .on("locationerror", function myPositionNotFound() {
        alert("Could not retrieve user location");
      });
  }

  //add features
  function addFeatures() {
    L.geoJSON(foos, {
      onEachFeature: addPopup
    }).addTo(map);
  }

  function addPopup(currentFeature, layer) {
    currentFeature.properties.distance = Math.round(
      calcDistance(myPosition.getLatLng(), currentFeature)
    );
    layer.bindPopup(
      "<img src=" +
        currentFeature.properties.logo +
        " alt=" +
        currentFeature.properties.title +
        "height='50' width='50'>" +
        "<h2>" +
        currentFeature.properties.title +
        "</h2>" +
        "<h4>" +
        currentFeature.properties.description +
        "</h4>" +
        "<h4>Avstånd: " +
        currentFeature.properties.distance +
        " m.</h4>"
    );
  }

  function calcDistance(position, feature) {
    //getting the lat and lng of the feature coordinates - choose the corner with index 2 of the polygon
    var standCoord = L.latLng(
      feature.geometry.coordinates[0][2][1],
      feature.geometry.coordinates[0][2][0]
    );
    return position.distanceTo(standCoord);
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };
})();
mapApp.init();
```

Comment: Remove in `map.locate()` the watch property. Then the update should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't get the correct distance in the addPopup() function. Variable myPosition remains unchanged.

Comment: Try `loactecontrol.start()` https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol#methods else is the location automaticly updateing? If not, put `map.locate()` in a `setTimeout()` loop.`function updaetLocation(){map.locate(); setTimeout(function(){ updaetLocation() }, 500);}`

Comment: I am not allowed to make any changes to my html/install other libraries etc.